# Creating manager levels in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create levels of managers within a dataset I have. It looks similar to this:

```
EID   ReporngManager       ManagerLevel1        Manager Level2        ManagerLevel3
123        201                    101                201                    301
124        101                    101                204                    306
125        401                    101                206                    304
```

The "EID" is the employee the Reporting manager the is ID of who they report to and the Mangers Levels starting at 1 is the highest level manager to 3 being a lower level manager. What I want is to be able to create another column that ranks the level of the manager's ID.

Something like this:

```
EID   ReportingManager   ManagerLevel1    Managerevel2   ManagerLevel3   ReportingManagerLevel
123          201              101              201            301                  1
124          101              101              204            306                  0
125          401              101              206            304                  3
```

The idea is to see how far the reporting manager is away from the top level. If the Reporting manager is the top then 0 and everyone that reports to him would be a 1. if the EID is reporting to the level 2 manager then that manager is 1 away from the top manager and all the EIDs would then be 2 away from the top. So far I have been just working on getting the managers' levels figured out but run into an issue of all managers having a Manager level of 3.

My code looks like this:

```
manager_level = []
num = list(df['ID'])
for num in df['ReportingManager']:
    if num is df['ManagerLevel1']
        manager_level.append('0')
    elif num is df['ManagerLeve2']:
        manager_level.append('1')
    elif num is df['ManagerLevel3']:
        manager_level.append('2')
    else:
        manager_level.append('3')
 df['Manager_Level'] = manager_level
```

*Note:* the 'df['postitonNum'] contains the ID of all the managers and employees.

Comment: try `manager_level = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel1']:
        manager_level.append(0)
    elif row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel2']:
        manager_level.append(1)
    elif row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel3']:
        manager_level.append(2)
    else:
        manager_level.append(3)
df['ReportingManagerLevel'] = manager_level`

Answer (score 1):

Reproduced you df with this:

```
import pandas as pd

data={
    "EID":[123,124,125], 
    "ReportingManager": [201,101,401], 
    "ManagerLevel1": [101, 101, 101], 
    "Managerevel2": [201, 204, 206],
    "ManagerLevel3": [301, 306,304], 
} 

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I suggest leveraging the report numbers themselves. `101 = 0`, `201 = 1` and so on. Assuming you use pandas based on the `df` variable and `dataframe` tag you can use the `apply` method as such:

```
import math
df["ReportingManagerLevel"] = df["ReportingManager"].apply(lambda x: math.floor(x/100)) -1
```

This will take the values of the *Reporting Manager* and find the starting number, then take away 1. This would mean that if you had a manager with the ID 502 it would get the value 4. If this is something you would like to avoid you could always use the `modulo` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Insted of use `in` you need to use the equality operator `==` to compare the values in the columns.

You can try with this code :

```
manager_level = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel1']:
        manager_level.append(0)
    elif row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel2']:
        manager_level.append(1)
    elif row['ReportingManager'] == row['ManagerLevel3']:
        manager_level.append(2)
    else:
        manager_level.append(3)
df['ReportingManagerLevel'] = manager_level
```